# meta class doesn't get inherited

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

In the following code:

```py
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        print(name)
        return type(name, bases, attrs)

class A(object, metaclass=Meta):
    def do_complex_task(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def do_minor_task(self):
        pass
```

I'd expect to see both `A` and `B` get printed, but I see that the meta class is applied to the `A` only. How can I solve this? My goal is to preprocess fields of all the children of `A`, and I'd like to omit typing `metaclass=Meta` in every child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you return `type(name, bases, attrs)` you get an object of type `type` instead of `Meta`. You can check this by printing `A.__class__`. Instead you should return:

```py
return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
```

Comment: AivanF.: Also, while what you have isn't wrong, the declaration of the base class can be shortened to simply `class A(metaclass=Meta):`.

Answer (score 1):

Your metaclass is not actually `Meta`. If you do `type(a)`, you get `<class 'type'>`, because you overrode `Meta.__new__` to return an ordinary `type`, not a `Meta` instance.

Generally speaking, like with ordinary classes, with metaclasses you want to override `__init__` and let `__new__` do the default thing.

```
class Meta(type):
    def __init__(self, name, supers, attrs):
        print(name)
```

Then you'll see both `A` and `B` printed, as desired.